# SecurityException on list GetItems

Tags: sharepoint-online, security

I'm using custom list event receiver on SharePoint Online to process some field in the item.

In the Event Receiver, I use a query to another list to retrieve value from that list in to current item. But whenever I call `GetItems(query)` or `list.Items`, it return server error. In logs I found SecurityException as below:

```
System.Security.SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.
   at ........SetValue(SPListItem thisItem, SPWeb thisWeb)
   at ........ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
The action that failed was:
LinkDemand
The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
MyComputer
```

This issue only happens after Microsoft's update on SharePoint Online (to 15 version), this code has been working for 6 months.

Anyone also facing same problems? Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause, it was `HttpUtility` that causes the SecurityException, not the `GetItems`. Fixed by using `SPEncode` instead.